# error sending mail using apache james

Tags: apache, jakarta-mail, james

I am using apache james 2.3.2. I went to telnet localhost 4555 and created new user test....when I am sending mail I am getting error Error message:
553 #5.1.8 Domain of sender address test@localhost does not exist. Requesting you to kindly help me out.

Comment: copy/paste actual telnet results please.

Answer (score 0):

> Let's add a few users before moving on. To do that, telnet to
>   localhost on port 4555 with the command telnet localhost 4555. You can
>   log in with the root user name and password. After the login, we'll
>   add a few users.

Looks pretty [simple](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-james1/index.html).